# typecasting char variable into unsigned int

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I am trying to convert char variables into Unsigned int. my code is

```
char spi(char data) 
{ 
    //Start transmision 
    SPDR = data; 
    //Wait for transmision complete 
    while(!(SPSR & 0x80)); 
    return SPDR; 
} 

unsigned int ReadAd(void) 
{ 
    unsigned int data; 

    ChipSelectAd(1); 
    //Read data 
    CheckStatus();                                            
    spi(0x58);                                                
    data = (spi(0xFF)<< 8);    
    data |= spi(0xFF);         

    return data; 
}
```

Actually my problem is The spi function return an 8bit char so the above code shifts left 8bits the char variable and then assigns it to a 16bit variable, the result will always be 0.
In order to actually shift the data to the left I need to typecast them first to a 16bit type variable. I have tried like this

```
char spi(char data) 
{ 
    //Start transmision 
    SPDR = data; 
    //Wait for transmision complete 
    while(!(SPSR & 0x80)); 
    return SPDR; 
} 

unsigned int ReadAd(void) 
{ 
    unsigned int data; 

    ChipSelectAd(1); 
    //Read data 
    CheckStatus();                                            
    spi(0x58);                                                
    data = (unsigned int)((unsigned char)spi(0xFF)<< 8);    
    data |= (unsigned int)((unsigned char)spi(0xFF));         

    return data; 
} 

void CheckStatus(void)
{
//char adcStatus;
adcStatus = 0xFF;                                           
//Read status
while(!(adcStatus & 0x80))
{
    spi(0x40);
    adcStatus = spi(0xFF);
 }
}

void ChipSelectAd(char s)
{


if(s == 1){
    PORTB.3 = 0;    //Switch on ADC
    //while(PINB.3);  //Wait for chip select pin
}
    else
        PORTB.3 = 1;    //Switch off ADC
 }
```

its not working. please suggest me which function i have to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually get any new data out of `SPDR`? How is `SPDR` defined? Is it something like `*(char*)SOME_ADDRESS`? If it is, is there a `volatile` in there, like this?: `*(volatile char*)SOME_ADDRESS`. The same holds for `SPSR`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Yes it must be defined as volatile. These are standard SPI hardware registers.

Comment: @Lundin "must be defined" as in "they are defined" or as in "shall be defined"?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze If you don't declare them as volatile, your compiler may go complete haywire and optimize all of the code, or do obscure optimizations. To make things worse, some MCUs clear the SPSR register by reading it, followed by a read to a data register. If the code doesn't do that, the flags will never be cleared and program will lock up, forever waiting for status flags.

Comment: @Lundin I know what can happen if there's no `volatile`, which is why I brought up the subject. I merely asked if you know for sure they are already defined with `volatile` (e.g. in some "standard" include file or hard-coded in the compiler) or there's a chance they aren't defined in this way (e.g. the OP defined them incorrectly or inherited incorrect definitions from somewhere/someone else).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze That's impossible to tell. Most likely there is a register map available either from AVR or some open-source folks. The suspicious, non-standard bit field notation used with the PORTB registers suggests that the compiler comes with a pre-made, non-standard register map.

Comment: @verendra What's the definition (or expansion if it is a macro) of SPDR? If you get 0 all the time it may be because spi() always returns 0. Can you rule that out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not the casts. It works the same without them, due to the integral promotion rules.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char spi ( char data )
{
  char SPDR = data;
  return SPDR;
}

unsigned int ReadAd ( void )
{
  unsigned int data;

  data = spi ( 0x81 ) << 8;
  data |= spi ( 0x42 );

  return data;
}

int main ( void )
{
  printf ( "Result %x\n", ReadAd() );
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs `Result ffff8142` on a system where char is a signed type. To get to the real problem, try assinging the values of spi() calls to variables and then print their values. Please also show us the declaration/definition of `SPDR`.

Comment: To be picky, there is one problem with `spi ( 0x81 ) << 8` though. `char` can be signed or unsigned, it is implementation-defined. Meaning that a 'char' type with MSB set will be treated as a signed and promoted to an int (signed). The code is then producing a signed int overflow, which is undefined behavior. Using left shift on signed ints is also undefined behavior. Just never ever use signed ints in anyform of bitwise operation and there will be no problems.

Comment: @Lundin Just looked up C99. Surprised to the fact that `negative value << count` is unconditionally undefined (including the case where simple addition (to achieve the effect of shifting/multiplying by a non-negative power of 2) would not cause an overflow). Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze It is only undefined behavior if the result cannot be represended, ie if the sign bits are overwritten.

Comment: @Lundin Um. It says "If E1 has an unsigned type, the value... If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 * 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." With this wording, negative signed E1s fall under the "otherwise" clause with UB.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Yes exactly. My point was, if you have a `signed int E1 = 1;` and then do `E1 << 4`, then 1*2^4 _is_ representable in the result type (assuming two's complement), it is _not_ undefined behavior. So the undefined behavior doesn't depend on the type, it depends on whether you cause an overflow or not when you shift.

Comment: @Lundin Not quite exactly. `(-1)+(-1)` does not cause an overflow and therefore does not cause UB. But according to that paragraph from C99, `(-1)<<1` causes UB, even though there doesn't seem to be a good reason for it and one would expect `(-1)<<1` to be equivalent to `(-1)+(-1)` or `(-1)*2`, neither of which causes overflow/UB.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze -1 is, on a two's complement 32-bit computer, 0xFFFFFFFF. Computers have either logical or arithmetic shift instructions, but the C standard enforces logical shift only. Thus 0xFFFFFFFF << 1 results in 0xFFFFFFFE. Whether this ends up as a signed or unsigned number depends on what happens to be shifted into the MSB. In this case it ended up signed, but if we had 0xDFFFFFFF it would have ended up without a sign. If C allowed arithmetic shifts, it would be another story. But C makes no assumptions about the signedness of the CPU, and therefore we end up with undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin I don't follow it. The quoted portion of C99 operates with types and values in the conditional clauses ("if (un)signed", "if nonnegative") and not with bit representations or patterns. "ifs", which differentiate normal behavior from UB, occur before/when the shift is attempted, not after and they take into account the not-yet-shifted "E1". What the CPU does is unrelated to this text.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze What the C standard is saying is "logical left shift away on signed ints as much as you like, but we don't know the underlying signedness implementation of the CPU and take no responsibility for any trap representations or overflows your shifting might cause." The bit representation of your particular CPU then determines whether it works or not. The standard enforces no static type checking or such to save you from the UB.

Answer (score 1):

1) in embedded systems: get rid of the standard integer types, the default char type in particular. If you have a modern compiler, use uint8_t, uint16_t etc from stdint.h. If you have an ancient compiler, then `typedef unsigned char uint8_t` and so on. If you aren't using unsigned types of known size in embedded systems, you are asking for bugs bugs bugs.

2) Learn and understand [integer promotion rules](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules). It is frightening how many programmers there are that don't know about them or understand them.

Once you have the two above fundamentals sorted out, your code should look something like this code:

(I took the liberty to fix various suspicious, possible bugs and the crappy, inconsistent indention. Plus some style nitpicks.)

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t spi (uint8_t data) 
{ 
  SPDR = data; //Start transmision 

  while((SPSR & 0x80) > 0) //Wait for transmision complete 
    ; 

  return SPDR; 
} 

uint16_t ReadAd(void) 
{ 
  uint16_t data; 

  ChipSelectAd(true); 

  CheckStatus(); //Read data 
  (void) spi(0x58);                                                

  data  = ((uint16_t)spi(0xFF)) << 8;
  data |=  (uint16_t)spi(0xFF);

  return data; 
} 

void CheckStatus(void)
{
  uint8_t adcStatus;

  do
  {
    (void) spi(0x40);
    adcStatus = spi(0xFF);
  } while((adcStatus & 0x80) > 0);
}

void ChipSelectAd(bool on)
{
  if(on)
  {
    PORTB.3 = 0;    //Switch on ADC
  }
  else
  {
    PORTB.3 = 1;    //Switch off ADC
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd still recommend to ditch the uint16_t casts. They are useless clutter.

Comment: I'd also say that there is a perfectly reasonable use of the plain char type: when used for strings and string functions. Using pointers to plain char is the only way to avoid casting pointers for functions expecting plain char (because supplying a ptr-to-(un)-signed-char would *require* a diagnostic without a cast).

Comment: @Jens i have tried in your way can you suggest me once what wrong with my code , i am new to controllers please suggest me.

Comment: @Jens Regarding the cast: suppose you know that spi() always returns a large, positive value and have `array[spi(0xFF) + negative]`, where negative is a plain int with a negative value. Since you didn't keep track of your types, that code will crash and burn. Because you'd have uint8 - int, then integer promotion, uint16 - int, then balancing uint16 - uint16. Array far out of bounds. If you had an explicit type cast there, then you would perhaps be more careful when writing that line.

Comment: @Jens Regarding the char type: This is blatantly obviously raw binary transferred over SPI. The char type may have a purpose when used in strings, but I'd question that. Statements like `ch - '0'` are dangerous because you could end up with a signed result, that you then pass on to some bitwise operations and invoke undefined behavior.